# Facebook Messenger shows notification while open

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

Whenever I have Facebook Messenger open, I continue to get notifications for chats that I am presently viewing. That is, I will be reading a chat, and as a new message comes in, I get a peek notification for it even though the chat is already open. Is this normal behavior, or is there some way to fix this without having to hack something out on Tasker?

I don't use chat heads, and the only settings I have on for notifications are Notification Previews and Light (LED).

On Android 7.1.1, though I had this problem on 6 on my previous phone as well.

Comment: Are you referring to peek notifications? I never used Facebook though, but I suspect you're referring to those

Comment: Yes, peek notifications, thank you. Forgot what they were called.

Comment: Yes this is normal behavior AFAIK.  iOS does have more options for notifications then Android does.  You could disable notifications all  together for messenger and use tesla unread(costs $5) with nova launcher prime to just display the number only.  Not ideal.